# How to stylize or reduce quality of camera video in AS3 iOS?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, ipad

Might there be a way in AS3 on IOS to stylize with filters or drastically reduce the quality of an iPads camera output to make it look highly abstracted? The code here shows how it's working at the moment with bandwidth and quality set very low.

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.CameraPosition;
import flash.media.Video;

var camW: int = 1024;
var camH: int = 730;
var video: Video;

var rows: int = 7;
var cols: int = 9;
var pieceW: int = camW / cols;
var pieceH: int = camH / rows;
var pointArray: Array = new Array();

startCamera();

function startCamera() {
    var camera:Camera;
    camera = getCamera(CameraPosition.FRONT);
    camera.setMode(camW, camH, 30);
    camera.setQuality(10,2);
    video = new Video(camW, camH);
    video.attachCamera(camera);

    initpieces(); //chop video into pieces to create a jigsaw puzzle

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updatepieces);//keep updating each pieces video
}

function initpieces(): void {
    for (var r: int = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (var c: int = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            var piece: MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            piece.name = "piece" + r + c;
            var p: Point = new Point(c * pieceW, r * pieceH);
            piece.x = c * (pieceW) + pieceW / 2;
            piece.y = r * (pieceH) + pieceH / 2;
            pointArray[piece.name] = p;

            var bmpd: BitmapData = new BitmapData(pieceW, pieceH);
            var bmp: Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpd);
            bmp.name = "myBmp";

            piece.addChild(bmp);
            bmp.x = -pieceW / 2;
            bmp.y = -pieceH / 2

            addChild(piece);
        }
    }
}

function updatepieces(e: Event): void {
    var srcBmpd: BitmapData = new BitmapData(camW, camH);
    srcBmpd.draw(video);
    for (var r: int = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (var c: int = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            var b_mc: MovieClip = this.getChildByName("piece" + r + c) as MovieClip;
            var bmp: Bitmap = b_mc.getChildByName("myBmp") as Bitmap;
            var p: Point = pointArray[b_mc.name];

            bmp.bitmapData.copyPixels(srcBmpd, new Rectangle(p.x, p.y, pieceW, pieceH), new Point());
        }
    }
}

function getCamera(position: String): Camera {
    for (var i: uint = 0; i < Camera.names.length; ++i) {
        var cam: Camera = Camera.getCamera(String(i));
        if (cam.position == position) return cam;
    }
    return Camera.getCamera();
}
```

The result is a little fuzzy and not very abstract at all.

Ideally I'd like to gradually increase the quality until the viewer realizes the image is from their own camera.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally I'd like to gradually increase the quality until...

I did not test your code but.. Are you trying to make a longer (transition time) version of this effect?

- http://as3adventure.blogspot.com/2011/04/pixelization-transition.html

Also you could try this one: (ps: use a timer to update `myMoz.pixelSize = 10;`)

- http://juliankussman.com/blog/2008/10/01/as3-bitmap-mosaic-class/

Anyway you can look at their source codes and get ideas for your own BitmapData object...

Comment: Interesting effect but can't see how to apply it to live camera video. It would be great if there was a way...

Comment: The first link? I haven't tried it myself but it looks like `mosaicTrans(pic,1);` does it where **pic** would be your displayObject to adjust. Try it by using that demo code this way: Have a sprite/MC container on stage called **pic** into it you addChild video object. You should now see your video pixelating instead of the tree image when you run that. You'll need to get tweenlite (its linked there) 'cos it's dependant on that for animated scaling